# Add array as a property to the object of collection in mongodb

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, mongodb

I have an object saved on MongoDB and the array property of the object needs to be added if the array is empty and needs to be updated if there is the same productCode in the array.
Currently, since I just added this property to the Category class, I don't have the "products" property on the DB and I want to add it first then if it's added, I'd like to update it by productCode.

The object of the collection:

```
[EntityCollectionGroup("categoryCollection")]
public class Category: BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Product[] products {get; set;}
}
```

Product object that needs to be added/updated(**if the same productCode exists on the array**):

```
public class Product
{
    public string productCode { get; set; }

    public string productName { get; set; }

    public double productPrice {get; set; }

    public int productAmount { get; set; }
}
```

I have used the code part by referencing the link but nothing happened on DB.

> https://kevsoft.net/2020/03/23/updating-arrays-in-mongodb-with-csharp.html

```
private async Task UpdateProduct(Product product)
        {
            var filter = Builders<Category>.Filter.Eq(c => c.Id, product.Id)
                & Builders<Category>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.products, Builders<Product>.Filter.Eq(x => x.productCode, product.productCode));
        var update = Builders<Category>.Update
                      .Set(c => c.products[-1].productCode, product.productCode)
                      .Set(c => c.products[-1].productName, product.productName)
                      .Set(c => c.products[-1].productPrice, product.productPrice)
                      .Set(c => c.products[-1].productAmount, product.productAmount);


        await Collection<Category>().UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
    }
```

Comment: Another example that works
https://github.com/iso8859/learn-mongodb-by-example/blob/main/dotnet/01%20-%20Begin/10%20-%20UpdateNestedArray.cs